# Move During playing Jump Animation

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation

So the case is that I have a 36 frames long jumping animation and the jump itself starts at frame 12, where my object raises along y axis.

1. What would be the most easiest way to move my object forward while it's in air(during frames 12-36)?
2. How is jumping with animation generally done in games? I don't think my way is the best one. But I would also like to know how its usually done in my way too. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just read the comments and your question. Why not write this code:

***Whenever You want him to jump at whatever condition:***

***Here I'll show you how to do it onClick of Space i.e, whenever you click space the jump animation plays whatever animation you have now the object moving in y-axis***

```
if(Input.GetKeyDown(Keycode.Space))
{
yourPlayerAnimator.setBool("TheAnimatorCondition",true); //Bool for your animation to play if u have a idle with you.
}
if(yourPlayerAnimator.GetBool("TheAnimatorCondition")== true)
{
transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime)
}
```

***All these Happens inside void update***

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the answer. I tried implementing this. But im still having my player just play his animation but not move forward

Comment: So I still have this issue any fix?

Comment: Whats exactly happening then?

Comment: He is just staying in the same place like how my animation is

Answer (score 0):

[Animation transition](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Transition.html) is your friend.

Put any condition when jumping to move to another animation. In this case i.e. when pressed left displacement key, move from "jump" to "jump&moveleft" or similar and when unpress return to jump state increasing the frames you spent moving to left.

Comment: So you also want me to create a animation that jump & also moves left or the direction  i want.

Comment: Any ideas on how to programmatically move forward with the current scenario